# How do I add more functionality to child method?

Tags: php, class, inheritance, methods, extend

parent_says() method says something, now I want to add more functonality to parent_says() method but from inside child class. How do I do it?

```
    class Parent_class{
    function parent_says(){
        echo "HI. I'm parent!";
    }
}

class Child_class extends Parent_class{
    function parent_says(){
        //I want it to also says "HI. I'm parent!", that's inside parent method.
        echo "I say hello!";
    }
}

$Child_class = new Child_class;
$Child_class->parent_says();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `parent::` to call the parent class' method first. E.g.

```
class Child_class extends Parent_class{
    function parent_says(){
        parent::parent_says();
        echo "I say hello!";
    }
}
```

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php) for more information.

Comment: Why am I unable to call parent method like so: $this->parent_says() ?

Comment: Because `$this` refers to the current object, and you've overridden that method. If you were to rename your child's method, then you could certainly do it that way.